# how to get a date from a date input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

hello so i have a javascript function that takes two dates from two date inputs, compares them and returns a boolean value except it doesn't work

```js
function checkdate() {

 var datefrom = new Date();
 var dateto = new Date();


 datefrom = getElementById("date_from").innerHTML;
 dateto = getElementById("date_to").innerHTML;

 if (datefrom > dateto) {
  alert("Dateto must be bigger than datefrom  ");

  return false;
 } else return true;

}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkdate()" class="forms-sample" method="post"
   action="addstage.php">
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="exampleInputUsername2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Date
      Début</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
         <input type="date" class="form-control"
            id="date_from" placeholder="Debut" name="datedebut"  required="required">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Date
      Fin</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
         <input type="date" class="form-control"
            id="date_to" placeholder="Fin" name="datefin" required="required">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check form-check-flat form-check-primary"></div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" value="addStage"
      name="action">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should use `.value` property, *not* `.innerHTML` to access the value of an input element.

Comment: After you fix the .value issue, You are comparing strings, not Dates.

Comment: @epascarello `"2020-06-01" > "2020-05-30"` works just fine, but sure, parsing the values into proper Date objects could have some benefits.

Comment: @pawel and if the date format is not MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: @epascarello then you're dealing with a non-compliant browser implementation of the date input :) Format of the returned `value` is defined by the spec and doesn't have to match the displayed date which most likely will be locale-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You're calling `getElementById` globally, but should be calling it on the `document` object.
2. You're using `.innerHtml` instead of `.value`

As an aside you also don't need to create `new Date()` objects just to throw them away.  Simply set the values you want right away:

```
var datefrom = document.getElementById("date_from").value;
var dateto = document.getElementById("date_to").value;
```

**Note:** These values are *strings*, not *dates*.  According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> **The displayed date format will differ from the actual value** — the displayed date is formatted *based on the locale of the user's browser*, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.

So for comparison purposes this should still work, since `yyyy-mm-dd` is an incrementing value.  But if you need a `Date` object then MDN also says there's a `.valueAsDate` property (though has no example on that page), as well as a `.valueAsNumber` which returns a UNIX timestamp that should be reliable for creating a `Date`.

Otherwise dates can be tricky in JavaScript, and libraries like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) exist to make that easier.

Comment: Comparing strings, not dates

Comment: *valueAsDate* parses the date as UTC, not local.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `getElementById` as a [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) method. You have to call it on `document`:

```
datefrom= document.getElementById("date_from").innerHTML;
dateto= document.getElementById("date_to").innerHTML;
```

Comment: More issues than this